# Coinspot API in Node.js

Tags: node.js

does anyone know how to make a post request from Coinspot API? The information of how to put the API key, secret and nonce is not very clear

---

All requests to the POST API requests will need to include the following security data.

Headers key - Your API key generated from the settings page sign - The POST data is to be signed using your secret key according to HMAC-SHA512 method. Post Params nonce - Any integer value which must always be greater than the previous requests nonce value.

---

I am trying to create a REST API, but I am getting a 401 request error. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```html
const axios = require("axios");
var n = require("nonce")();
const crypto = require("crypto");

const api_key = process.env.COINSPOT_KEY;
const api_secret = process.env.COINSPOT_SECRET;

let nonce = n();
let postdata = { nonce: nonce };

function getSecurePassword(password, salt, algo) {
  const algoFormatted = algo.toLowerCase().replace("-", "");
  const hash = crypto.createHmac(algoFormatted, salt);
  hash.update(password);
  const res = hash.digest("hex");
  return res;
}

exports.orderHistory = async (req, res) => {
  let sign = getSecurePassword(api_secret, JSON.stringify(postdata), "SHA-512");
  try {
    await axios({
      baseURL: "https://www.coinspot.com.au/api/v2/ro",
      url: "my/orders/completed",
      port: 443,
      method: "post",
      data: postdata,
      headers: { key: api_key, sign: sign },
    }).then(function (response) {
      res.json(response);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without converting the digest to hex - this is not necessary.

The rest of the code looks OK - you are setting the post data in the body and adding the signature header correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to use the Coinspot API and while reading the docs there is an SDK called 'coinspot-api'.

- SDK: https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinspot-api

Aswell while looking through the module files you can see how data is fetched

- dir path:  /node_modules/coinspot-api/coinspot.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).